# Domino Designer: Access selected rows from embedded view

Tags: view, formula, lotus-domino, lotusscript

Once again I have a question concerning Domino Designer.

---

There are newsletters which should be assigned to several contacts.

Therefore I built a form containing a combo box to select the newsletter.
Beneath, there is an embedded view containing all available contacts.

```
Combobox:
 _______________________
| ComboBox Newsletter  ⇓|
 -----------------------


Embedded View:
__________________________________
  |  Name   | Lastname |  Company |
-----------------------------------
   John       Smith        ABC 
 • Anna       Tylor        XYZ      (<- Anna is selected)
   Michael    Williams     ZYX

Button:
 ________
| Submit |
```

The idea is, to choose the newsletter, select each of the desired contacts (by selection margin) and hitting a button afterwards. The magic, which should be done by the button is to assign the chosen newsletter to each of the selected contacts by appending it to the intended multiple value field in the contact form.

But how to I find out which rows are selected by either `Formula`, `LotusScript` or `JavaScript` (favored in this order :-P )?

`@GetFocusTable` produced no valuable results for me.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this if you run the code from an action in the action bar of the embedded view. This must be a view action of the embedded view

I don't think you can do that with @Formulas. What you need is LotusScript. You can get the handle on the selected documents using the UnprocessedDocuments property of the NotesDatabase class. Here are some details and a code example: 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21279380

To display the action bar in the embedded view you must enable the option "Show action bar" in the properties of the embedded view.

[image]

View in designer:

[image]

This is how it should look like then in in the notes client:

[image]

Comment: Hi Michael.

Once again you're trying to help me. Have another thx from me ;)

I was able to create a new action. But it is displayed on the very top of the form. I expected it in the embedded view, or am i wrong?
Nevertheless, I used the following code as suggested in your link:
     `Set col=db.UnprocessedDocuments     
     Msgbox( "Col-size: " & col.count)`

But the collection always counts 0. I activated the option, you pointed out. I guess I a have to assign the action in some way to the embedded view, but I couldn't figure out how. Sorry about that :(

Comment: Hi Markus, the action button must be created as a view action of the view which is embedded. This will then be displayed in the embedded view (has an own action bar). See my update above.