# Lotus script agent does not make any update when ran from an Embedded View in lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I have an embedded View within my form which has a bunch of agents in the embedded view.

However when i select rows(documents) in the embedded view and run the agent (eg "Do a multi profile update") it does work but it does not make any changes to the documents selected. Like the prompt in the lotus script agents does work and pop up but no updates are made.

When ran externally from the view it works fine so for some reason it does not work from an embedded view is what i feel.

The agent within the view is an Action which uses a formula language code `@Command([RunAgent];"updatePeople")`

were the updatePeople is a lotus script agent.

any ideas or suggestions guys?

Comment: What are the trigger and target options in the agent properties set to?  What does the agent's LotusScript code look like?  How is it accessing the documents? And what do you observe in the debugger when you run it from the embedded view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to access the selected documents using an action in the embedded view with the LotusScript logic inside the acrtion instead of calling agents. You can find a complete answer here (with full explanation and code sample):

[Domino Designer: Access selected rows from embedded view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585695/domino-designer-access-selected-rows-from-embedded-view/14586313#14586313)

I am not sure if this IBM TechNote explains exactly the same issue, but it seems very similar: 
[How to get a handle on selected documents in an embedded view when using LotusScript](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21279380)

Comment: Awesome Michael got it working the problem was that i was calling agents. so i used the action in the embedded view with the LotusScript logic. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Does the ID have the correct ACL settings for the agent to run?
Does the ID have the ability to edit documents?
Does the Agent have the proper save statements in the code?

The example code in the above link is doing a full db search of unprocessed documents. I would suggest using the ViewEntry document collection. This will allow the agent to run faster since the view could be customized.

Another way to go if you are having issues with processing is to set up a flag field that is updated with the save of your document. The flag field could be used in your view selection field to have the documents fall out of the view if that is desired.

Comment: If the agent is set to run against "All Selected Documents", then UnprocessedDocuments only runs against documents that "Are selected in the view" or "Meet the search criteria specified in Agent Properties box". Check the help documentation. If changing a value that causes a document to drop out of the view, you also have to be careful about how you get the next document in the view, since the one that "dropped out" is no longer available as a reference within the view once you do that.